# Parsing JSON Values Through jQuery is eliminating 1st value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am storing a PHP array variable in Jquery variable.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
<script>
    var tagger = '<?php echo json_encode($tags); ?>';
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(tagger);
    $.each(obj, function(key,value)
       {
          $("#post_tags").tagging("add", value);
       });
</script>
```

In tagger variable, I am getting this below data.

```
var tagger = '["sdf"," da"," adf"," ad"]';
```

But when I am running the loop it is showing values from the second index, the first index value is being eliminated.

Only these values are visible in the field : `'[" da"," adf"," ad"]'`.
The `sdf` value is not displayed.

May I know that where is it being wrong, as far as I am concerned the code is good to go. But still, want to confirm that is there anything missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    // try this
    var obj = <?php echo json_encode($tags); ?>;
    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(tagger);
    $.each(obj, function(key,value)
    {
      $("#post_tags").tagging("add", value);
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: what does console.log(obj) gives in console

Comment: `(4) ["sdf", " da", " adf", " ad"]
0: "sdf"
1: " da"
2: " adf"
3: " ad"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: one more error i spotted `Uncaught TypeError: f[b] is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (tagging.min.js:223)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.e.fn.tagging (tagging.min.js:220)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (post.js:149)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)`

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to parse the tagger because it already in json format:**

```
<script>
    var tagger = <?php echo json_encode((array)$tags);?>;
    $.each(tagger, function(key,value)
       {
          $("#post_tags").tagging("add", value);
       });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried doing this, it gives the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in ["sdf"," da"," adf"," ad"]`

Comment: can you var_dump the $tags?

Comment: `array (size=4)
  0 => string 'sdf' (length=3)
  1 => string ' da' (length=3)
  2 => string ' adf' (length=4)
  3 => string ' ad' (length=3)`

Comment: Either it's [JSON](http://json.org) and need to be parsed or not. There's no such thing as a  _"json format"_.